# Android Studio Tab to Spacing in Flutter(Dart)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

How can I change tab to space in Android Studio 4.0 ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since Dart does not have language-specific settings in Android Studio. Change ***use tab character*** or not in ***Other File Types*** options, which is for all file types that aren't separately available for options.

**Editor** > **Code Styles** > **Other File Types** > Uncheck **Use tab character**.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by editing the configuration file.

I use Linux, mine was located at
~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/codestyles/Default.xml

```
<codeStyleSettings language="Dart">
  <indentOptions>
    <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
    <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="4" />
  </indentOptions>
</codeStyleSettings>
```

If there is already a section for Dart, just add indent options, or else add the whole snippet just after <code_scheme> or just before </code_scheme>.

For IntelliJ users config file locations are given here -
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Android Developer and cannot leave Android Studio, since it's your coding home, but can't let go of flutter either.

**Changing tab size won't work through `Default.xml` in `codestyles`.**

**Use a different theme:** **Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme** (this auto adjusts indentation and makes code look exactly as of Visual Studio Code). To install theme - plugins -> search "Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme"

**OR**

**Use a different font:** I prefer

Font : "Droid Sans Mono Slashed" or "Monospaced" (You can use any that works for spacing)

Font size: 18 , Line Height 1.4 // For 14 inch screens

Font size: 14 , Line Height 1.2 // For 15.6 inch screens or larger

[image]

**OR**

**A combination of above looks beautiful.**

[image]